# How to use Python for online GIS?

Tags: python, web-mapping

I consider myself a GIS expert, and I have successfully completed many GIS projects for clients. I am proficient in spatial analysis, ArcGIS, QGIS, and quite good in Python as well. However, I am only proficient in desktop GIS solutions (i.e. making PDF, image, KML solutions). Sometimes, I run into clients who would prefer a more attractive solution to show to their investors, rather than just a PDF map. That tears me down because I don't know the web mapping technologies.

My last client asked me to find the best locations in a city where he could build stores for his business. So, we're dealing with GIS suitability analysis here. Normally, the work would require finding GIS layers (e.g. population distribution, income distribution, park locations, etc.) and combine those layers to produce a final hotspot map that would reveal the best locations. I could make an image/pdf/kml map for this, but the client would prefer a web map instead which would consist of a base map (e.g. Google Maps), and the transparent final hotspot map on top of it. The ideal solution would also include some sort of option/area on the webpage where the user could define the weights coefficients of the criteria layers and have the hotspot map created once the weights are entered. For instance, if the user thinks that the park layer is very significant then they could enter 0.8 (at a 0 to 1 scale), 0.6 for the income layer etc. Defining the weights could be in the form of a slider bar. I understand that this solution would need the algorithm to work on the background every time the user sets weights, and I know how to do that in Python.

I am also aware that Javascript would be a tool for this solution. However, I would prefer to do the entire webpage in Python only. So here come the questions: Is it possible to do all that using Python as the scripting language? What would you suggest me to learn for implementing an online solution like the one I just described concerning a GIS suitability algorithm?

Comment: I think this is too broad because, as you say, "here come the questions" and answers that are likely to include opinions on how best to do Online GIS. I recommend focussing on a particular requirement and describing what you have tried/researched related specifically to it, and where you are stuck. An answer to that may answer all your questions or uncover what next to ask using our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Probably just indicating that you are only open to Python answers in this question would restrict its scope enough. You can always explore other options separately. I think it is a great question, just too broad for focussed Q&A in its current form.

Comment: just upload the resulting layer to arcgis.com

Answer (score 4):

One of the most popular web framework for Python is Django. It contains GeoDjango (GeoDjango intends to be a world-class geographic Web framework. Its goal is to make it as easy as possible to build GIS Web applications and harness the power of spatially enabled data).

Here is a documentation and tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/

About creating a simple geoportal in GeoDjango wrote E. Westra in his book Python Geospatial Development.

With this tool, postgis and Javascript (Openlayers) you will be able to create nice online geoportal, wich can visualize spatial data and users can perform spatial analyses.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/) is what you're looking for.  It is an extension of the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework which is Python based.  You'll still need HTML/CSS/Javascript for formatting the site but Django helps with some of that and GeoDjango does the heavy lifting when it comes to your GIS data.

Comment: Would I need a database for implementing the GIS suitability application too?

Comment: Not necessarily, but depending on the size of the data your hosting and the types of operations you're running a database could help.  PostGIS has built in functions for finding distance, intersects, etc and is a good way to store and serve up data. For example, it can respond to a query with a geojson of your spatial data, and you can display that geojson directly in a Leaflet or Openlayers map.

Answer (score 1):

With web pages I have primarily stuck to JavaScript, CSS, and HTML. I have put together a few web pages/applications that use solely those three. I also do not have any Python experience so I am not fully sure of all of its capabilities, although I hear that it is powerful. I would suggest to look into learning some of these languages that I listed to better understand what is capable on both ends, since you are already proficient in Python. Some things Python may be better at implementing and some things JavaScipt may be better at implementing.

In JavaScript I could most likely use the Google Maps API and add the various maps, layers, KMLs into the map. Then I would create toggle functions with checkboxes to show the different maps with the different coefficients.

Some great places to start with learning these to help your vision become a reality would consist of:

W3 Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/

Google Maps API for Developers: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Again I do not know much about python so I am sure you will get some answers that may be more straight to the point and up your alley. But it never hurts to learn new languages. Happy coding.